# Self-signing standalone applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-2.0

All of my previous attempts to find any information about this subject have lead to an unending stream of outdated information. We have a bunch of standalone utility programs that we use internally at the company I work for (just an executable and any required dll's). This works well, however since they are not signed there is a security warning every time you open any of these utility programs.

In an ideal world I would like to be able to generate a certificate and use that to sign the binaries with visual studio instead of having to purchase a cert from Verisign or some other Root CA.

I need to be able to sign the applications then copy the executables and necessary dll/config files from the `bin/Release` folder so that anyone logged in to our domain can run them without a security warning.

The .Net 2.0 restriction is not absolutely necessary, but all of these utility applications are built against 2.0 for backwards compatibility with XP.

Comment: Is it a security warming or a UAC warning because it requires admin rights?  Is it some sort of domain policy? Are you running the code from a network locationor locally on each pc?

Comment: Self signing won't help. Since you are inside the firm, so use your internal CA to grant yourself certificates to do so.

Comment: @RonBeyer None of the applications require admin rights.

Comment: @LexLi If you could provide a link with more information that would be terrific.

Comment: @DavidFreitag it heavily depends on your firm environment, so I could not comment more. You might check out things such as Active Directory Certificate Services if your firm uses AD.

Comment: In theory you can use AD (or manual copy+paste) to roll out a new CA (with code-signing enabled) to all users and then issue all your devs code-signing certs from that CA. Afterwards you should be able to automatize code-signing with VS.

Answer (score 0):

For your signed code to be accepted by Windows, Windows needs to be able to verify the integrity of said code. Thus the code needs to be signed by a trusted authority, which puts us at a 5-step process:

1. Generate a trusted root CA. "trusted" may only refer to your company here.
2. Deploy this trusted root CA to all users of the software.
3. Create a certificate template for code-signing.
4. Distribute code-signing certs to all the developers.
5. Automatize the signing process.

Now let's go through all these steps:

1. This step "really depends". You *could* use OpenSSL to generate the root CA. You *could* use a dedicated tool like [XCA](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) or [EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/). Or you *could* use the [Windows Enterprise CA feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875810.aspx).
2. This one is greatly facilitated by using Windows Active Directory, as you can just setup a new group policy that will distribute the new certificate to all the users and mark it trusted. Also see [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315(v=ws.10).aspx) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/358995/285953).
3. This is kindof an optional step, but you can (and should?) create a template using your favorite CA management tool so that issueing a new code-signing certificate is a shorter process. You may be forced by your tool to do this or skip it. [Here's how it's done in Windows Server.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731705(v=ws.10).aspx)
4. In this step you either use [the Windows tool to automatically create and distribute certificates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753452(v=ws.11).aspx) or each developer creates a [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) and sends it to you so you can issue the certificate (using your favorite CA management tool) which they can later use.
5. Visual Studio can be setup to automatically use a key that Windows knows you own. [Comodo conveniently has already collected the steps to do this.](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1062/38/how-do-i-automate-code-signing-in-visual-studio)